# $group and $lookup is not giving proper data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am having code like this

```
const aggregate = [];
const lookup = {
  $lookup: {
    from: "balances",
    localField: "accountNumber",
    foreignField: "account_id",
    as: "bankbalance",
  },
};
const unwind = {
  $unwind: "$bankbalance",
};
const match = {
  $match: {
    "bankbalance.date": {
      $gte: startDate,
      $lte: endDate,
    },
    userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
    isActive: 1,
    type: "accountType"
  },
};
const group = {
  $group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    accountNumber:{"$first":"$accountNumber"},
    balances: {
      $addToSet: { date: "$$ROOT.date", amount: "$$ROOT.amount" },
    },
  },
};

aggregate.push(lookup);
aggregate.push(unwind);
aggregate.push(group);
aggregate.push(match);

let data = await BankAccounts.aggregate(aggregate);
```

this code is giving me empty [] data, if I do not use $group then its giving data like this

```
{
_id: 611bc2c4f9649b2c6fe4007f,
bankId: 'string',
mask: '0000',
name: 'Plaid Checking',
userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
accountNumber: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
createdAt: 2021-08-17T14:08:04.058Z,
isConnected: true,
subtype: 'checking',
type: 'depository',
updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:36:37.824Z,
isActive: 1,
bankbalance: {
  _id: 61262b9bf9649b2c6fe7d67c,
  ISODate: '2021-05-19T00:00:00.000Z',
  account_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
  ISOCountryCode: null,
  accountId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  amount: -1047.62,
  bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  createdAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z,
  current: null,
  date: '2021-05-19',
  institutionId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  isActive: 1,
  unofficialCountryCode: null,
  updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z
 }
},
{
_id: 611bc2c4f9649b2c6fe4007f,
bankId: 'string',
mask: '0000',
name: 'Plaid Checking',
userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
accountNumber: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
createdAt: 2021-08-17T14:08:04.058Z,
isConnected: true,
subtype: 'checking',
type: 'depository',
updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:36:37.824Z,
isActive: 1,
bankbalance: {
  _id: 61262b99f9649b2c6fe7d671,
  ISODate: '2021-05-24T00:00:00.000Z',
  account_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
  ISOCountryCode: null,
  accountId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  amount: -1137.02,
  bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  createdAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z,
  current: null,
  date: '2021-05-24',
  institutionId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  isActive: 1,
  unofficialCountryCode: null,
  updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z
 }
}
```

this is giving all data record again and again, here reference between 2 collection is accountNumber and account_id. I want to group all records in 1 like

```
{
_id: 611bc2c4f9649b2c6fe4007f,
bankId: 'string',
mask: '0000',
name: 'Plaid Checking',
userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
accountNumber: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
createdAt: 2021-08-17T14:08:04.058Z,
isConnected: true,
subtype: 'checking',
type: 'depository',
updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:36:37.824Z,
isActive: 1,
bankbalance: [{
  _id: 61262b99f9649b2c6fe7d671,
  ISODate: '2021-05-24T00:00:00.000Z',
  account_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
  ISOCountryCode: null,
  accountId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  amount: -1137.02,
  bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  createdAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z,
  current: null,
  date: '2021-05-24',
  institutionId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  isActive: 1,
  unofficialCountryCode: null,
  updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z
 },
 {
  _id: 61262b9bf9649b2c6fe7d67c,
  ISODate: '2021-05-19T00:00:00.000Z',
  account_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  userId: 611bc2794d9f391bf2cd7877,
  ISOCountryCode: null,
  accountId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  amount: -1047.62,
  bankTokenId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  createdAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z,
  current: null,
  date: '2021-05-19',
  institutionId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  isActive: 1,
  unofficialCountryCode: null,
  updatedAt: 2021-08-25T11:37:26.960Z
 }
]
}
```

also sort bankbalance by date. Any help! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The stages are in the order

```
aggregate.push(lookup);
aggregate.push(unwind);
aggregate.push(group);
aggregate.push(match);
```

When the group stage executes, each document will have only the fields noted in that stage. i.e.

```
{
  _id: 611bc2c4f9649b2c6fe4007f,
  accountNumber: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  balances: [ {date: ......, amount: .....} ]
}
```

When the match stage executes, the fields `"bankbalance.date"`, `userId`, `isActive`, and `type` don't exist, so no documents satisfy the match.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but I am using same order. I need to group all records in one record under balances. Whatever I have written its not working.

Comment: You will need to either match before you group, or change the match stage to only examine fields that actually exist after grouping.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that works const group = {
    $group: {
      _id: '$accountNumber',
      balances: {
        $addToSet: { date: "$bankbalance.date", amount: "$bankbalance.amount" },
      },
    },
  };

Comment: Sort before grouping will probably be easiest.

Comment: const sort = {
    $sort: { "bankbalance.date": -1 }
  }; and I used this before group, but its not working